# How to change default project's structure for Android project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is it possible to change the folder structure of /res directory when IntelliJ IDEA creates a new Android project?

Namely, the default structure contains only 5 folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, values and layout) and I would like to have more folders created by default, so that I do not have to manually add those folders each time I create a new Android project.

The good thing would be to create more class files in a row as well (especially those I use in each project) or even include my own libraries, but I do not think this is achievable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA is using [android create project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) command line way, so you get the same structure as you would get when creating the project manually. There is no way to customize it inside IDEA.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know is there a way to change the SDK command? How do you handle this: manually create folders each time or copy/paste empty project?

Comment: There is no way to change the command. If all your projects are common, I'd use copy/paste and then create IDEA project on top from the existing sources.

Comment: Please file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA and we'll consider adding template projects for Android.